# Jms message acknowledge only till the message acknowledged on

Tags: java, jms, messaging, qpid

How to ensure message acknowledge deletes only messages upto the message on which acknowledge is called in a jms broker.
Currently I have a system which consumes from a jms queue and partially processes it.Sometime later a batch of these messages gets persisted by a different thread. I need to acknowledge on messages now. But the problem is I have to stop consuming the messages, otherwise acknowledging a previously received message will also acknowledge all other subsequent messages received.

In other words suppose I have 10 messages in a queue. I consume 7 of them, and then acknowledge on 5th message. This in turn removes all 7 messages received by consumer from the queue.Is there a way to only acknowledge and remove messages from queue till 5th message.

EDIT: I have tried creating two sessions and consuming from different sessions, but (with apache qpid atleast) this performs inconsistently. By inconsistently I mean, sometimes during the test it so happens that one consumer is able to receive messages, while the other doesn't receive at all, no matter how long you wait. This would have worked for me as a solution, but because of inconsistency can't use this as a solution.

Comment: You have not specified which message provider you are using. But as far as I know many messaging providers don't allow random message acknowledgement. If you acknowledge one message, all messages received till that point will also be acknowledged and removed from queue

Comment: I use apache qpid, and I am not doing a random acknowledgement, but doing acknowledgment on a particular message. Its ok if all messages before that gets cleared, but if further messages have been received, they also get removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I understand this post is old, but this answer should benefit those who stumble upon it later.

If you'd like fine grained control of which messages you'd like to acknowledge, the `individual` acknowledge method should help you. Using this acknowledgement mode you can ack individual messages in a session. Messages that have not been ack-ed will be redelivered.

This is not part of the spec, but most queue providers support it outside the spec.

## [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19717-01/819-7757/aeqeg/index.html)

> For more flexibility, Message Queue lets you customize the JMS
>   client-acknowledge mode. In client-acknowledge mode, the client
>   explicitly acknowledges message consumption by invoking the
>   acknowledge() method of a message object.
>
> The standard behavior of
>   this method is to cause the session to acknowledge all messages that
>   have been consumed by any consumer in the session since the last time
>   the method was invoked. (That is, the session acknowledges the current
>   message and all previously unacknowledged messages, regardless of who
>   consumed them.)
>
> In addition to the standard behavior specified by JMS, Message Queue
>   lets you use client-acknowledge mode to acknowledge one message at a
>   time.

```
public interface com.sun.messaging.jms.Message {
          void acknowledgeThisMessage() throws JMSException;
          void acknowledgeUpThroughThisMessage() throws JMSException;
}
```

## [ActiveMQ](https://java.net/jira/browse/JMS_SPEC-95)

> One can imagine other acknowledge modes that would be useful too, for
>   example: CONSUMER_ACKNOWLEDGE where Message.acknowledge() would
>   acknowledge only messages received up on a particular MessageConsumer,
>   or CONSUMER_CHECKPOINT_ACKNOWLEDGE where Message.acknowledge() would
>   acknowledge only messages received up to and including the Message
>   instance on which the method was called.
>
> But without embarking on all these various different possibilities,
>   would it be possible to consider just adding INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE
>   mode? This alone would make it possible for multithreaded applications
>   to achieve whatever behaviors they need.

```
connection.createQueueSession(false, ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

I have not used QPID personally, however the [documentation hints](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-0.22/messaging-api/ruby/api/classes/Qpid/Messaging/Session.html#M000009) to the fact that individual message acks are possible.

```
Examples
  # acknowledge all received messages
  session.acknowledge

  # acknowledge a single message
  session.acknowledge :message => message
```

While processing a batch you can ack each message that is received and processed. If you encounter an exception, do not ack the message.

Answer (score 1):

Acknowledging a message will make the queue manager to remove that message plus all other messages received before that message. It should not remove the messages which have not yet been received by an application. You may want to check your application on how you are acknowledging a message.

Comment: The problem is all messages received by consumer is removed, and its not dependent on the message you are acking on. I want to implement something which only removes upto a certain message, even though I might have received more messages after that. This is needed, because I process messages in batch, and whenever a batch processing is complete, I need to ack till that batch. And this batch processing is time consuming so I want to continue receiving messages in parallel

Comment: No, that's not possible. All received messages will be removed when one message is acked. You may need to look at alternatives.