# Camel, Akka, JMS and deferred message acknowledgement: can I acknowledge a previously processed message to the broker?

Tags: scala, jms, akka, activemq-classic, akka-camel

I am using Akka (latest stable version), `akka-camel` and JMS (for the purposes of this conversation, let's say it's ActiveMQ, but ideally the solution should be generic).

#### The use-case

I have the following use-case. On a queue `Q` I receive messages like this:

```
time:   1     2    3    4    5    6

      | A1 | B1 | C1 | C2 | A2 | B2 | .... 
         ^                        ^
       first                     latest
```

My end goal is to pair them together in `(A1,A2)`, `(B1,B2)`, and so on; notwithstanding complications like duplicates and undelivered messages, the complication is that I have to ensure that, until a whole pair is matched and processes, **the broker will keep hold of all unacknowledged messages.**

#### Example

At `4` I received and processed 4 messages, and processed successfully  pair `(C1, C2)`, however I still cannot acknowledge anything back to the broker because `A1` and `B1` are still unmatched and pending, and in JMS **to acknowledge `C2` means to acknowledge all messages up to `C2`**. As a matter of fact, the first acknowledgement I can send back is at time `5`, when `A2` is received: at this point I can acknowledge `A1` (and only `A1`, as `B1` is still pending).

#### The problem

Now, what I can't seem to figure out is how to do this kind of *delayed* and *async* acknowledgement via `akka-camel`. I have been reading online and, while I can find explanations on how to acknowledge messages manually ([docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/camel.html#Delivery_acknowledgements) and an [example](http://tethys.ro/blog/2016/02/03/akka-camel-activemq-delivery-acknowledgement/)), there is nothing showing how to acknowledge a previously processed message to the broker.

```
import akka.camel.{ CamelMessage, Consumer }
import akka.camel.Ack
import akka.actor.Status.Failure

class Consumer3 extends Consumer {
  override def autoAck = false

  def endpointUri = "jms:queue:test"

  def receive = {
    case msg: CamelMessage =>
      sender() ! Ack
      // on success
      // ..
      val someException = new Exception("e1")
      // on failure
      sender() ! Failure(someException)
  }
}
```

In this case, `Ack` is an `object` and its semantic is really just: **I acknowledge the current message** while I would need something like **Message X is now acknowledged**, where **X** is some previous message, but not necessarily the current one.

Is this use-case supported or supportable via `akka-camel` or should I just build it myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is activemq's [ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQSession.html#INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE).

Sadly INVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE is not part of the JMS spec, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396000/jms-message-acknowledge-only-till-the-message-acknowledged-on) post that behvaiour it is widely adopted on a per queue basis. (I haven't actually checked)

Since it's not on spec, akka doesn't support it out of the box, but it sure would make a good contribution!